# Two Forms Binding WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm still learning WPF and I tried to make simple score program that use two form. The first form as the Control Panel, and the second one as the display. However I couldn't find the way change the value in the Display form when I change the value in the Control Panel. I googled it, It said I could use Binding. Would you like to help me please? Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="Score.Control"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Score"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Control" Height="300" Width="400" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="400" Background="#FF181818" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtJudul1" Foreground="#FF00AADE">Judul 1</TextBox>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtJudul2" Foreground="#FFC6C6C6">Judul 2</TextBox>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Margin="2">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtNamaA" Foreground="#FF8A9B0F">A</TextBox>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtScoreA" Foreground="#FFFCA910">1</TextBox>
                </Viewbox>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Button x:Name="btnTambahA">+</Button>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Button x:Name="btnKurangA">-</Button>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Viewbox>
                <Button x:Name="btnDisplay" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,5" Click="btnDisplay_Click">
                    DISPLAY</Button>
            </Viewbox>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC6C6C6"> VS </TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtPointA"  Foreground="#FFF14D0F">x</TextBox>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC6C6C6">-</TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtPointB" Foreground="#FFF14D0F">y</TextBox>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="6">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Button x:Name="btnReset" Height="20">R</Button>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Button Name="btnSwitch">S</Button>
                </Viewbox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Margin="2">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtNamaB" Foreground="#FF8A9B0F">B</TextBox>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtScoreB" Foreground="#FFFCA910">0</TextBox>
                </Viewbox>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Button x:Name="btnTambahB">+</Button>    
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Button x:Name="btnKurangB">-</Button>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
<Window x:Class="Score.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Score"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FF181818" 
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtJudul1" Foreground="#FF00AADE"> Judul 1 </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC6C6C6"> Judul 2 </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF8A9B0F">A</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFCA910">1</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC6C6C6">VS</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFF14D0F">x</TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFC6C6C6">-</TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#FFF14D0F">y</TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FF8A9B0F">B</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFFCA910">0</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Clemens : I just don't understand.. How can I change texblock in Form2 by setting its value from textbox in Form 1?

Comment: By binding both controls to the same property in the same instance of a view model class. Also search the web for MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a sample application based on your needs and uploaded here :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fiia3wpu8pnrkf/General.rar?dl=0

I have kept everything as simple as possible as you are a new to WPF, and so have skipped Commands, MVVM etc.

Few points regarding this upload :

1. You can extract and run without issues.
2. In your XAML code, I have made changes where you show Player names/scores. Like : `<TextBox x:Name="txtNamaA" Text="{Binding Item1.Name,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="#FF8A9B0F"/>`.
3. This 2-way binding magic works because of INotifyPropertyChanged.
   Our business entities are presented below :

   ```
        using System;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

         namespace General.Score
         {
            public class ControlPanel
             {
                 static Tuple<PlayerScore, PlayerScore> _playerPairs;
                 public static Tuple<PlayerScore, PlayerScore> playerPairs { get { return _playerPairs; } }
                 static ControlPanel()
                 {

                    PlayerScore p1 = new PlayerScore() { Name = "A", Score = 0 };
                    PlayerScore p2 = new PlayerScore() { Name = "B", Score = 0 };

                    _playerPairs = new Tuple<PlayerScore, PlayerScore>(p1, p2);
                  }
              }

              public class PlayerScore : INotifyPropertyChanged
               {
                   String _name;
                   public String Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }    

                   int _score;
                   public int Score { get { return _score; } set { _score = value; OnPropertyChanged("Score"); } }

                   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                   private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
                   {
                      if (PropertyChanged != null)
                          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
                   }
               }
   ```

   }

See the figure below : 
            [image: Solution explanation]

Comment: please mark this as answer too if it fits your needs.

Comment: thank you very much
but I'm still confuse
What Is Item1?
`<TextBox x:Name="txtNamaA" Text="{Binding Item1.Name,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="#FF8A9B0F"/>`

Comment: Tuple<int, int, int> bestOfThree = new Tuple<int, int, int>();
now type bestOfThree. intellisense will show Item1, Item2, Item3 as our tuple contains 3 items.